# How to return two JSX elements in React to be rendered in different places?

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a sub component responsible for handling some user input

```
function MyInputComponent(props: {...}) {
  return <input>...</input>;
}
```

Now say I want to add a button to control that input, normally I would do:

```
function MyInputComponent(props: {...}) {
  return <>
    <input>...</input>
    <button>...</button>
  </>;
}
```

This works so far. But now I want to render the button at some other places (i.e. not within the same component). e.g. if we look at the final html, I want to have the button to be after another component:

```
<parent-component>
  <input>...</input>
  <some-other-component>...</some-other-component>
  <button>...</button>
</parent-component>
```

Of course, one way is to pass in <some-other-component> to `MyInputComponent` for it to render, but I want that code separation as `MyInputComponent` has nothing to do with that other component. And I don't want the parent component to handle the parameters for the <button> either as all the control logic (e.g. onClick action, etc.) are local to `MyInputComponent` only.

Is there a way to return {<input>, <button>} to the parent component, so that it can render them at desire places?

Comment: That should have been it, you want to insert a fragment. What is the `<parent-component>` doing to consume the children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `array` instead of `fragment`

```
const [MyFirstComponent, MySecondComponent] = () => {
    return [
        <h1>Element 1</h1>,
        <span>Element 2</span>
    ];
}
```